# find the MEMORY that an Object uses using Guava library

Tags: guava

I want to find the MEMORY that an Object uses, using Guava library. For that I have made the homework of searching and I have found out one class: CollectionUtils. It has a method size(Object). But my question is whether this method returns the size of the object or size  of the memory that it uses?

Comment: Uh.  Guava doesn't have a class called `CollectionUtils` or any tool that measures memory consumption.  Are you thinking of [MemoryMeasurer](http://memory-measurer.googlecode.com)?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find out how much memory something is consuming, then you want memory-measurer.googlecode.com.  But I don't think it's oriented toward beginners.

Answer (score 0):

It's not Guava but [Apache commons](http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html#size%28java.lang.Object%29) and it returns the number of elements. For memory usage there are tools based on instrumentation. Or you can use reflection and count it yourself. Or
allocate a lot of such objects and measure the memory used via `Runtime.totalMemory()` and `Runtime.freeMemory()`.